Angular Material table data loading issue
I have a issue with sorting and pagination of a angular material table. Source code is as given below.
 ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("ngOnInit started");
    this.shoppingcartService.GetShoppingCart().subscribe({
      next: (data: ShoppingCart) => {
        this.shoppingCart = data;
        console.log("data loaded");
        this.shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems.forEach((item) => {
          item.productName = item.product?.name;
        });
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems);       
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
      },
      complete: () => {  
      }
    });
    console.log("ngOnInit ended");
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() { 
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit started");
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; 
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit end");
  }

code of the "GetShoppingCart" method is this
  GetShoppingCart() : Observable<IShoppingCart> {
    let url = global.serverBase + "/api/ShoppingCarts/GetShoppingCartAsync";
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('content-type','application/json')  
    .set('mode','no-cors')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    return this.httpClient.get<IShoppingCart>(url,{'headers':headers}).pipe(
      map((data:IShoppingCart)=>{ 
        return data;
      }),
      catchError((error,caught)=>{
        throw error;
      })
    )
  } 

backend Api method
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetShoppingCartAsync")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetShoppingCartAsync()
{
   //code................ 
}

console logs are in the above "ngOnInit" and "ngAfterViewInit" methods are printed in this order

According to console logs, ngAfterViewInit is called before data are loaded. how can I correct this?.

Why does it matter? The data will come when the server responds and the data are constructed and available, not before. Also, you don't need to/shouldn't send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the request as it is a response header. It belongs on the API server.

try to move all code from ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit. and move dataSource = ... into next callback.

Always you create a new dataSource, you should indicate again the sort and paginator properties. So, just add the this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; inside your subscribe function -after the this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(..). Yes, you can remove the ngAfterViewInit function.

I fixed the issue by changing the code. The paginator and the sort bound like this.
  paginator: MatPaginator= new MatPaginator(new MatPaginatorIntl(), ChangeDetectorRef.prototype);
  sort: MatSort= new MatSort();
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
  @ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    this.sort = ms;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

I removed ngAfterViewInit() method and used the ngOnInit() method to assign the paginator and the sort properties in complete section.
  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.shoppingcartService.GetShoppingCart().subscribe({
      next: (data: ShoppingCart) => {
        this.shoppingCart = data; 
        this.shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems.forEach((item) => {
          item.productName = item.product?.name;
        });
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.shoppingCart.shoppingCartItems);
      },
      error: (error: any) => { },
      complete: () => {   
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;  
      }
    }); 
  } 

